# Next.js is not building page as SSG when it should

Tags: javascript, build, next.js, prismic.io

I am trying to understand why Next.js is building some of my pages as SSG and some of them as Static, when they all are using getStaticProps.

Let's take my 404 page that uses getStaticProps to fetch data from prismic with graphql. It is being rendered as a Static website when in my opinion it should be rendered as SSG (because it uses getStaticProps).

I am doing the EXACT same thing in my 500 page, but with a different graphql query and it is being rendered (in my opinion correctly) as SSG.

Why is that?

404 page:

```
const NotFound = ({ data: { page } }) => {
    return (
        <div className={'not-found'}>
            <p className={'not-found__description'}>{RichText.asText(page.description)}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const currentLanguage = getCurrentLocale(context);

    const response = await apolloClient.query({
        query: gql`
            query {
            }
        `
    };

    return {
        props: {
            data: {
                page: response
            }
        }
    }
});

export default NotFound;
```

500 page:

```
const InternalServerError = ({ data: { page } }) => {
    return (
        <div className={'internal-server-error'}>
             <p className={'internal-server-error__description'}>{RichText.asText(page.description)}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const currentLanguage = getCurrentLocale(context);
    
    const response = await apolloClient.query({
        query: gql`
            query {
            }
        `
    });
    
    return {
        props: {
            data: {
                page: response
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Current-Deployment-Details]

The 404.tsx or 404.js page in Next.js is unique in that it does not rely on the server and is always Static -- relying solely on static html (no json) *at build time* -- even when using `GetStaticProps` in the file.

The 404 page is simply a catch all `funnel` route that users are redirected to when navigating to paths that do not exist with your site as the base URL. So, it doesn't rely on the server on initial build. It's the fallback for paths not existing, and nothing else. The 500 page, on the other hand, handles an internal error in your application so it *does* rely on both `.html` and `.json` file types to pinpoint the nature of the error.

Interestingly, if you examine the contents of your `.next` directory locally, you'll notice that all pages using `GetStaticProps` have `.json` and `.html` files statically generated. Pages using `GetStaticProps` with `revalidate` returned === `Incremental Static Regeneration`, or `ISR`. `ISR` is an ideal hybrid of `SSG` and `SSR`, having background functions scanning for incoming changes/updates in production (the number you specify being the amount of time in seconds between possible updates). So, pages with `GetStaticProps` + `ISR` generate three file types in the `.next` directory -- `.html`, `.json`, and `.js`. That said, Pages using `GetServerSideProps` or `GetInitialProps` have only `.js` files generated in the `.next` directory. Lastly, pages that are purely `Static`, using none of the aforementioned methods, have only `.html` files generated.

The idea behind the 404 page and its Static nature is to enhance UX by expediting the rendering (or more correctly prerendering) of a custom `oops! that path doesn't exist` page so that a user can return to the actual application asap.

For example, I have the following in my `404.tsx` page, but it still renders as Static `html` *at build time*.

```
import { Container } from '@/components/UI';
import { initializeApollo, addApolloState } from '@/lib/apollo';
import { NotFound } from '@/components/NotFound';
import { AppLayout } from '@/components/Layout';
import {
    GetStaticPropsContext,
    GetStaticPropsResult,
    InferGetStaticPropsType
} from 'next';
import {
    NotFoundQuery,
    NotFoundDocument,
    NotFoundQueryVariables,
    DynamicNavQuery,
    DynamicNavDocument,
    DynamicNavQueryVariables,
    WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum,
    WordpressMediaItemSizeEnum,
    WordpressPageIdType
} from '@/graphql/generated/graphql';

export function SOS({
    notFound,
    Header,
    Footer
}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
    return (
        <>
            <AppLayout title={'✂ 404 ✂'} Header={Header} Footer={Footer}>
                <Container clean className='fit'>
                    <NotFound notFound={notFound} />
                </Container>
            </AppLayout>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps(
    ctx: GetStaticPropsContext
): Promise<
    GetStaticPropsResult<{
        notFound: NotFoundQuery['NotFound'];
        Header: DynamicNavQuery['Header'];
        Footer: DynamicNavQuery['Footer'];
    }>
> {
    const params = ctx.params!;
    console.log(params ?? '');
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    await apolloClient.query<
        DynamicNavQuery,
        DynamicNavQueryVariables
    >({
        query: DynamicNavDocument,
        variables: {
            idHead: 'Header',
            idTypeHead: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idTypeFoot: WordpressMenuNodeIdTypeEnum.NAME,
            idFoot: 'Footer'
        }
    });

    await apolloClient.query<NotFoundQuery, NotFoundQueryVariables>(
        {
            query: NotFoundDocument,
            variables: {
                id: '/404-not-found/' as '/404/',
                idType: WordpressPageIdType.URI,
                size: WordpressMediaItemSizeEnum.LARGE
            }
        }
    );
    return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
        props: {},
        revalidate: 60
    });
}
export default SOS;
```

Interestingly, because I do use `GetStaticProps` and `revalidate` for `ISR` in my `404.tsx` page, the contents of the `.next` directory reflects this as all three file types are present for `404` (`.js, .json, .html`). If you use `getInitialProps` in your custom `_app.tsx` or `_app.js` file, then automatic static optimization (the prerendering of static pages) will be disabled across the entirety of your app. Give it a try if you're curious, it should cause the 404 page to have a lambda next to it in your build log. However, since you already have `GetStaticProps` that should override the app-wide static deoptimization caused by your root `app` page using `GetInitialProps`

For example, I used `GetInitialProps` in `_app.tsx` prior to creating a custom `404.tsx` page some time back. I decided to pull the build logs and took an accompanying screen shot.

```
Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`.
```

[image: 404-static-deoptimization]

Comment: Ok, but the Next.js docs say 'This file is statically generated at build time. You can use getStaticProps inside this page if you need to fetch data at build time.' (404 & 500 pages). Shouldn't both pages be built the exact same way?

Comment: I agree that they should be, and I think they indeed are, if you examine the contents of the `.next` directory you'll see that you have all three file types (js, json, html) when using GetStaticProps + ISR in the 404 page. That said, perhaps the build logs reflect the following: "A 404 page may be accessed very often. Server-rendering an error page for every visit increases the load of the Next.js server. This can result in increased costs and slow experiences." It is static (html only) by default -- adding GetStaticProps overrides that. It's just the symbol remaining unchanged.

Comment: I just spent ~10 minutes sifting through their declaration files to determine how 404 vs 500 is handled under the hood to no avail. Going to ask a question on the nextjs repo about this, you raise a great point. All I can find info on === _error.d.ts with no explicit reference to 404 or 500 error pages.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems like an issue with Next.js

Answer (score 0):

Is the 404 page missing that parenthesis in your code?

```
const response = await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
        query {
        }
    `
};
```

should be

```
const response = await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
        query {
        }
    `
});
```

Comment: No, I am sorry. I missed that one.